# Is it true that $ S(x)^2 \geq S'(x)\int_{-\infty}^{x}S(t) \, dt$, where $S(x) = A\gamma(x) + \gamma(x-C)$ and $\gamma$ is the standard Gaussian?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory

For $C\geq0$ and $A\geq1$ define the function
$$
S(x) = A\gamma(x)+\gamma(x-C)
$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the standard Gaussian distribution in $\mathbb R$, $\gamma(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. Some numerical simulations suggest that the following inequality holds true:
$$
S(x)^2 \geq S'(x)\int_{-\infty}^{x}S(t) \, dt \qquad \forall x \in [0,C/2].
$$

I find it hard to prove this. Do you have any idea how to show this inequality?

Comment: actually, it seems to me that iit works only for $x\in [0,C]$

Comment: Yeah you're right, it should be $[0,C]$ - I changed it. Can you explain why it works for $x \in [0,C]$?

Comment: Not the full solution but the integral evaluates (after setting $x-C=t$) on the interval $[0,C]$:
$$
\int_{0}^{C}(A \gamma(x) + \gamma(x-C))dx = A(\Phi(C)-\Phi(0))+\Phi(0)- \Phi(-C)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $C > 0$.

We first give the following auxiliary results (Facts 1-3). The proofs are given at the end.

*Fact 1*: There exists $x_0\in (0, \frac{C}{2}]$ such that
$S'(x_0) = 0$, $S'(x) > 0$ on $[0, x_0)$, and $S'(x) \le 0$ on $[x_0, \frac{C}{2}]$.

*Fact 2*: $[S'(x)]^2 - S(x) S''(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, x_0]$ where $x_0$ is defined in Fact 1.

*Fact 3*: $[S(0)]^2 - S'(0)\int_{-\infty}^0 S(t) \mathrm{d} t > 0$. (The proof is not very difficult. Omitted.)

Now, by Fact 1, it suffices to prove that, on $[0, x_0)$,
$$f(x) \triangleq \frac{[S(x)]^2}{S'(x)} - \int_{-\infty}^x S(t) \mathrm{d} t \ge 0.$$
By Fact 2, we have $f'(x) = \frac{S((S')^2 - SS'')}{(S')^2} \ge 0$ on $[0, x_0)$.
By Fact 3, we have $f(0) > 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, x_0)$. We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: We have
$$S'(x) = (C-x)\gamma(x-C) - Ax\gamma(x)
= \gamma(x-C)[C - x - Ax \mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx}].$$
We have $S'(0) > 0$ and $S'(C/2) = \gamma(-C/2)C(1-A)/2$.

Let
$$g(x) = \ln(C-x) - \ln A - \ln x - \frac{C^2}{2} + Cx.$$
We have
$$g'(x) = \frac{C}{4x(C-x)}(C^2-4 - (C - 2x)^2).$$

We split into two cases:

1. $0 < C\le 2$: We have $g'(x) < 0$ on $(0, C/2)$.

1.1) If $A = 1$, since $g(C/2) = -\ln A = 0$, we have
$g(x) > 0$ on $(0, C/2)$. The desired result follows.

1.2) If $A > 1$, since $g(C/2) = -\ln A < 0$, there exists $x_0\in (0, C/2)$ such that
$g(x_0) = 0$, $g(x) > 0$ on $(0, x_0)$, and $g(x) < 0$ on $(x_0, C/2]$.
The desired results follows.

2. $2 < C$: Let $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}C - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^2-4}$.
   We have $g'(x_1)=0$, $g'(x) < 0$ on $(0, x_1)$,
   and $g'(x) > 0$ on $(x_1, C/2]$.
   It is easy to prove that $g(x_1) < 0$.
   Note that $g(C/2) = -\ln A \le 0$.
   Thus, there exists $x_0\in (0, x_1)$ such that
   $g(x_0) = 0$, $g(x) > 0$ on $(0, x_0)$, and $g(x) < 0$ on $(x_0, C/2)$.
   The desired result follows.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 2*: We have
\begin{align}
S'(x) &= (C-x)\gamma(x-C) - Ax\gamma(x), \\
S''(x) &= A(x^2-1)\gamma(x) + ((C-x)^2-1)\gamma(x-C),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&[S'(x)]^2 - S(x) S''(x)\\
=\ & A^2[\gamma(x)]^2 + [\gamma(x-C)]^2
- (C^2-2)A\gamma(x)\gamma(x-C)\\
=\ & [\gamma(x-C)]^2
[(A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx})^2 - (C^2-2)A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx} + 1]\\
=\ & [\gamma(x-C)]^2\left[\left(A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx} - \tfrac{C^2-2}{2}\right)^2 + 1 - \tfrac{(C^2-2)^2}{4}\right].
\end{align}

We split into two cases:

1. $0 < C\le 2$: Clearly, $[S'(x)]^2 - S(x) S''(x)\ge 0$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$.
2. $2 < C$: It suffices to prove that, on $[0, x_0]$,
   $$A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx} - \tfrac{C^2-2}{2} \ge \sqrt{\tfrac{(C^2-2)^2}{4} - 1}$$
   or
   $$A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx} \ge \frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}$$
   or (taking logarithm)
   $$x \le \frac{\ln A + C^2/2 - \ln(\frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2})}{C} \triangleq x_2.$$
   Clearly $x_2 > 0$. It suffices to prove that $x_0 \le x_2$. By Fact 1, it suffices to prove that $S'(x_2) \le 0$ or
   $$C - x_2 - Ax_2\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx_2} \le 0$$
   or (noting that $A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx_2} = \frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}$)
   $$C - x_2 - x_2\left(\frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}\right) \le 0$$
   or
   $$C - x_2 \left(\frac{1}{2}C^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}\right) \le 0.$$
   Since $\ln A \ge 0$, it suffices to prove that
   $$C - \frac{C^2/2 - \ln(\frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2})}{C} \left(\frac{1}{2}C^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}\right) \le 0.$$
   It is not difficult to prove it (Hint: Use the substitution $C = \frac{u^2 + 4}{2u}$ for $u > 2$).

We are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you explain the following step in the proof of fact 2 in more detail: "It suffices to prove that, on $[0,x_0]$ : $A\mathrm{e}^{C^2/2 - Cx} \ge \frac{1}{2}C^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{C^4 - 4C^2}$ "

Comment: @Muzi You are welcome. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show
$$
S(x)^2\geq S'(x)\int^{x}_{-\infty}S(t)dt\tag 0
$$
Let$$f(x)=\int^{x}_{-\infty}S(t)dt.\tag 1$$
Then your inequality is equivalent with the statement that $y(x)=\log(f(x))$ is strictly convex $\downarrow$ in $[0,C/2]\subset (-\infty,x_1]$, $C/2<x_1=x_1(A,C)\approx C/2$. That is because $f(x)>0$ in $(-\infty,x_1]$ and$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(f(x))=\frac{f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2}{f(x)^2}=\frac{S'(x)\int^{x}_{-\infty}S(t)dt-S(x)^2}{\left(\int^{x}_{-\infty}S(t)dt\right)^2}.$$
Also for small $x\in
(x_1,x_2)$, $x_2=x_2(A,C)$, we have $y''(x)\geq 0$.

The convexity of $\log(f(x))$ for $x>>1$ (actualy $x>x_2$) follows from the fact that $f(x)$ is positive (as mentioned above) strictly inceasing and have limit  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}S(t)dt=1+A<\infty.$$Hence for $x>>1$ we have $y(x)$ convex $\downarrow$.

However I use a different approach.

**Lemma 1.** Assume that $h(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, $a<b$. Then holds$$h(x)\geq0,\forall x\in[a,b]\Leftrightarrow\int^{y}_{x}h(t)dt\geq0,\forall x\leq y\textrm{ such }x,y\in[a,b]$$**Proof.** It is well known that if $h(t)\geq0$, then $\int^{y}_{x}h(t)dt\geq0$, for all $x\leq y$ with $x,y\in[a,b]$ . For the opposite we have that $\int^{x}_{a}h(t)dt\geq 0$, for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then assume that exists $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $h(x_0)<0$. Then from the continouity of $h(x)$ we can assume that exist $c,d:a\leq c<d\leq b$ such that $h(x)<0$ in $[c,d]$. Then $a\leq c<d\leq b$ and $\int^{d}_{c}h(t)dt<0$, which is imposible.

**Lemma 2.** Assume that $f(x)\in C^{2}(D)$, $D=[a,b]$, $a<b$ and $f(x),f'(x)>0$, $\forall x\in D$. Then
$$
f(w)\leq f(z)\exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}(w-z)\right)\textrm{, }\forall b\geq w\geq z\geq x\geq a\tag 2
$$
iff
$$
f(x)f''(x)\leq (f'(x))^2\textrm{, }\forall x\in[a,b].\tag 3
$$
**Proof.**
For all $t\in[a,b]$
$$
f(t)f''(t)\leq(f'(t))^2\Leftrightarrow \frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\leq\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\int^{y}_{x}\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}dt\leq\int^{y}_{x}\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt\Leftrightarrow 
$$
$$
\log\left(f'(y)\right)-\log\left(f'(x)\right)\leq \log\left(f(y)\right)-\log\left(f(x)\right)\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\log\left(\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}\right)\leq\log\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)\Leftrightarrow\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}\leq\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)},
$$
for all $x\leq y$ such that $x,y\in[a,b]$. Now assume $w\geq z\geq y$. Then for the function
$$h(y)=\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$It holds $h(y)\leq 0$, for all $y\geq x$ and using Lemma 1, we get
$$
\log(f(w))-\log(f(z))\leq \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}(w-z).
$$
Hence when $w\geq  z$  and $z,w\in[x,b]$, for all $x\in[a,b]$ we get
$$
\frac{\log(f(w))-\log(f(z))}{w-z}\leq \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.
$$
But since $f'(y)>0$ we get finaly
$$
\left|\log(f(w))-\log(f(z))\right|\leq \left|\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right|\left|w-z\right|,
$$
for all $w\geq z\geq x$, $a\leq x\leq b$. Hence
$$
f(w)\leq f(z)\exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}(w-z)\right),\tag 4
$$
for all $w,z,x\in[0,C/2]: C/2\geq w\geq z\geq x\geq 0$. QED

The function $f(x)$ of (1) is positive in $[0,C/2]$. If we prove that
$$
\frac{f(w)}{f(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2(w-z)^2-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}(w-z)-1\leq 0\tag 5 
$$
we are done (note that $e^t\geq t^2/2+t+1$, $\forall t\geq 0$).

[image: see image here]

Comment: Does the very last inequality indeed hold for the function $f$?

Comment: I have checked (5) in Mathematica but it not corresponds. However (4) works ok. If  you want not use the exponential,  then use  $e^t\geq t^2/2+t+1$, $t\geq 0$ this is ok. I have correct it in my  answer.

Comment: Could you write down the output of Mathematica? Somehow I still don't know how to prove the inequality formally ....